Delayed calling of a method
I have a method which calls a third party API, I need to check that, if the third party API takes more than three seconds to respond I want to show a delayed response in three seconds, but simultaneously, i want to store the response which i got from the third party API in the backend database table.
I have used used concepts of Cancellation token which worked for cancelling the API in 3 seconds, but i did not got the response which needed to be store in database, so i am using Timer method which might also not be the correct way to proceed.
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<ReponseClass>();
var timer = new Timer(async state =>
    {
        try
        {
            result = await methodWithThirdPartyAPICall((int)state);
            tcs.SetResult(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tcs.SetException(ex);
        }
}, device_id, 3000, Timeout.Infinite);

Can anyone help me with the solution or guide me with their experience?

You should use asynchronous method with the task cancel to achieve it, you will have two condition one condition is less than 3 seconds, then the response come back, if exceed 3 seconds cancel the first task and store the request details into a queue , then let a background task to execute the queue to get the result.

Have you looked into Polly: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly, a .Net library? https://www.pollydocs.org/strategies/timeout
